# i tried to run gazebo husky simulation but everytime i get a black screen on the gazebo!

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, husky, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my real time factor is zero
also the screen is completely black!
cant run the simulation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245073/i-tried-to-run-gazebo-husky-simulation-but-everytime-i-get-a-black-screen-on-the-gazebo!/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably because of your pc specs.

I have met a similar issue when I started using gazebo and I had to change pc to make it work. Be sure you don't have a low-end graphics card and a cpu technology that can handle the computational requirements of gazebo.

The most probable cause is the graphics card though.

Take a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements)

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0